# How to add shortcut to slide of contents in beamer?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, cross-referencing

I need to have shortcut on every slide to the content slide, which is located in the end of the presentation.

I was trying to do this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \hyperref[sec:main-content]{Content}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%

        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            %   \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} \hspace*{2ex}  / \hspace*{2ex} \inserttotalframenumber
            \hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Main}
        Main
    \end{frame}

    \section{First}
    \begin{frame}{First}
        First
    \end{frame}

    \section{Second}
    \begin{frame}{Second}
        Second
    \end{frame}

    \section*{Content}
    \label{sec:main-content}
    \begin{frame}{Content}
        \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But this scheme does not do what I want. Because by pressing on `Content` link it does not send me to the last slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
\hyperref[sec:main-content]{Content}
```

use

```
\hyperlink{sec:main-content}{Content}
```

A complete example (by the way, no need to load `hyperref` explicitly using `beamer`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \hyperlink{sec:main-content}{Content}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%

        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            %   \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} \hspace*{2ex}  / \hspace*{2ex} \inserttotalframenumber
            \hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Main}
        Main
    \end{frame}

    \section{First}
    \begin{frame}{First}
        First
    \end{frame}

    \section{Second}
    \begin{frame}{Second}
        Second
    \end{frame}

    \section*{Content}
    \label{sec:main-content}
    \begin{frame}{Content}
        \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can use the optional argument for `frame` to set the label:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \hyperlink{sec:main-content}{Content}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%

        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            %   \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} \hspace*{2ex}  / \hspace*{2ex} \inserttotalframenumber
            \hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Main}
        Main
    \end{frame}

    \section{First}
    \begin{frame}{First}
        First
    \end{frame}

    \section{Second}
    \begin{frame}{Second}
        Second
    \end{frame}

    \section*{Content}
    \begin{frame}[label={sec:main-content}]
    \frametitle{Content}
        \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```